# Can't open another Word document NetOffice C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, netoffice

The conditions are as follows. There is an opened Word document. When I try to open another document in this way:

```
var application = new Application    // the window appears on this line
{
    Visible = true,
    DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone,
}; 
var document = application.Documents.Open(pathToFile);
```

Microsoft Word Security Notice window pops up:

[image]

When I close this window manually, another Word document launches with no problem.
I have also tried to add a property:

```
var application = new Application
{
    Visible = true,
    DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone,
    AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
};
```

But that didn't help either. I found a post with a similar problem posted 5 years ago: [Disable Macros Automatically Microsoft Word Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230025/disable-macros-automatically-microsoft-word-interop?rq=3).

But I don't need to disable the ability to run macros, I just need to somehow make this window not appear. Or automatically close it. Judging by what I have read, it is almost impossible to do this. But hope dies last :)

P.S. This problem is not present in Excel and PowerPoint for some reason.

Comment: Specify [Trusted Locations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4). Additional information: [Application Guard for Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/application-guard-for-office-9e0fb9c2-ffad-43bf-8ba3-78f785fdba46)

Comment: `I just need to somehow make this window not appear.` so does every hacker. You can't just disable the end user's security settings to make your life easier. If you want to disable something, disable macros. Or make sure you only load trusted documents. The domain admin will be able to modify the trusted sources across a domain too, but the local AppData folder is certainly not a trusted location

Comment: I just want the Word application to behave the same way it does when I open another file manually. This window does not appear when I do the same in Excel and PowerPoint. Only in Word and only when trying to open a document when another document is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deal with this problem in this way:

```
var application = Application.GetActiveInstance() ??
                new Application    
                {
                    Visible = true,
                    DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone,
                }; 
var document = application.Documents.Open(pathToFile);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).